# resize and adjust the heatmap in heatmap.2

Tags: r, heatmap

I've generated a heatmap like this: 
[image]

The X-axis and Y-axis labels don't show completely. 
My code is here:

```
 heatmap.2(x,col=blueyelred,colsep=c(1:6),rowsep=(1:62), 
           sepwidth=c(0.05,0.05), sepcolor="white", trace="none",
           Rowv=F,Colv=F, scale="none", dendrogram="none",key=F, 
           lhei = c(0.05,5),margins=c(1,8))
```

Is there any way to adjust it.

Thanks!
Cam

Answer (score 13):

A few tips:

- to reduce the font size, use the `cexRow` and `cexCol` arguments, e.g.

  ```
  heatmap.2(x, ...., cexRow=0.5)
  ```
- Adjust the values in the `hlei` and `margins` arguments.

Answer (score 10):

I see that you are already using the `margins` parameter, what if you just modify the arguments as @csgillespie suggested?

e.g., `margins = c(8, 8)`

Maybe also modifying the general plot margins before calling the `heatmap()` function could help

e.g., `par(mar=c(10,4,4,2))`

or for the outer margin

`par(oma=c(10,4,4,2))`

where
`par(mar=c(bottom,left,top,right))`