# Pheatmap display_numbers argument

Tags: r, pheatmap

I need to use and show stars for significances within my `pheatmp`, I have utilised the approach below. 
As you can see the stars reported by the figure cross the cell border. Is there a way to centre it within the cell?

```
test_vals <- matrix(rnorm(20), 5, 4)
test_labels <- matrix(1:20, 5, 4) 
test_labels[test_labels<=10] <- "**"
pheatmap(test_vals, display_numbers = test_labels, fontsize_number=40, cellheight=20)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the answer to this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701207/column-labels-cropped-when-using-pheatmap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not find a straight way to solve your task, so I can suggest a little dirty hack. You can use a different asterisk symbol from Unicode (U+2217 ASTERISK OPERATOR). So try this:

UPDATE: it is possible to pass Unicode strings into plotting function without previous parsing. Therefore I have updated the code and removed `stringi` library requirement.

```
library(pheatmap)

test_vals <- matrix(rnorm(20), 5, 4)
test_labels <- matrix(1:20, 5, 4) 
test_labels[test_labels <= 10] <- "\u2217\u2217"
pheatmap(test_vals, display_numbers = test_labels, fontsize_number=20, cellheight=20)
```

Here is a result:
[image: Example result of pheatmap with the different Unicode character]

Also, you can try other variants. Next two are slightly bigger the common asterisk.

```
# Heavy asterisk
#test_labels[test_labels<=10] <- "\u2731\u2731"
# Full width asterisk
#test_labels[test_labels<=10] <- "\uFF0A\uFF0A"
```

Comment: I am having a problem in the visualisation of the asterisks. Heatmap reports indeed an empty centred box instead of the asterisks

Comment: Can you run this code in R console `stri_unescape_unicode("\u2217")`

Comment: Yes, I got this `"∗"`

Comment: It could be a problem with a graphics device on some systems (Windows, MacOS). Just for a test, can you save a plot with `cairo_pdf` function?

Comment: I tried `cairo_pdf` and `CairoPDF` but it does still show a square instead of the asterisk

Comment: Maybe your font doesn't contain additional symbols.  Try a different font. Look at `showtext` package. Here is a good tutorial https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/showtext/vignettes/introduction.html